# How to open a new tab for new module in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am importing multiple maven module through 'Existing maven Projects' tab from 'Import' section under eclipse.
But i am trying to know whether it supports/pop ups a new tab whenever i import a new module.
As of now, Project explorer having all imported module in single pane. I need it in invidual pane.

[image]

Comment: I not sure what you are asking, but Project Explorer just shows all projects in a single view.

Comment: Thanks for response @greg-449.I am asking to view every project in different window when i import another project. It should not show in single view. Because it will lead to confusion.

Comment: There is no way to do that. I have nearly 50 projects in one of my workspaces and don't find any problems with confusing them - the projects just need to be clearly named.

Comment: @greg-449 While i am opening my eclipse, it keeps lot of time to index for newly imported project under Project explorer due to many projects under project explorer pane. Therefore, i want some procedures that will remove all projects from explorer, but files would not delete. Alternatively, i was trying to open new window for newly imported projects. That's all from my side.